# How can I change time format setting?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, timestamps

Every time I enter stackoverflow from google and view some answers, I always get confused by timestamps like this:

```
answered Aug 25 '17 at 23:53
```

I am not native American or english native speaker and the time format is really strange for me, I have to spend time thinking on it about what time it is, cause what I familiar with from a child is ISO format like:

```
2017-08-25 23:53
```

Could you please make a setting option, please!

Comment: If you hover over the time you should get a tooltip that shows the datetime in ISO format.

Comment: It is mainly country-dependent, U.S. uses mm-dd-yyyy, Germany uses dd-mm-yyyy, and I know one other where the iso yyyy-mm-dd is the normal. Of course it is the smallest :-)

Answer (score 9):

As BSMP notes, this information is already baked into the page, as the title (hovertext) attribute on just about every timestamp.

But... That doesn't help much when you're on mobile, eh?

So add this bookmarklet to your bookmarks and sync with your mobile device, then just type the name on any page where you want to see full timestamps:

```
javascript:void $(".relativetime,.relativetime-clean").text(function() { return this.title; })
```

This results in:

[image: screenshot of this very question with full ISO timestamps]

Comment: No more jumping to the timeline and toggling to ISO timestamps!